# Почему в Sublime Text 3 не работает метод gets?

Tags: ruby, методы, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

В irb метод  gets  работает, но в Sublime Text 3 нет никакой реакции(можно билдить Ctrl + B).  chomp же вообще не определен. 
Вот пример кода:

```
name = gets.chomp
print name
```

Если убрать chomp, то в консоли снизу ошибка возникать не будет, но и возможности ввода данных так же не появится.
В общем как вводить данные в Ruby, используя  Sublime Text 3?
Может нужно подключать какую-то библиотеку или еще что-нибудь?

Comment: Sublime Text 3 это ж текстовый редактор. Где вы в нём код выполняете?

Comment: Ctrl + B - билдит

Comment: Допишите в вопрос :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию в Sublime Text нет терминала, поэтому когда вы запускаете билд, он выполняет весь скрипт и просто выводит результат всего выполнения в окно билда. Интерактивный ввод данных оттуда не поддерживается.

Однако есть [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) - плагин для Sublime Text, который добавляет возможность выполнения кода не покидая редактора. Ставится как и любой другой Sublime Text плагин (не забудьте перезапустить ST после установки плагина):

> <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd>  ⇒ Install Package ⇒ SublimeREPL

Плагин должен подхватить и использовать текущую активную версию ruby, с учетом rvm и rbenv. Для ruby требуется установленный гем pry (с последним pry могуть быть проблемы, в этом случае советуют ставить версию pry 0.9.12.6):

```
$ gem install pry
# или
$ gem install pry -v 0.9.12.6
```

REPL запускается через меню команд ST, откроется в новой вкладке:

> <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> ⇒ SublimeREPL: Ruby

После того, как REPL запущен, с ним можно работать как с irb в терминале, а также передавать на выполнение файлы, строки, выделенные фрагменты кода (см. [клавиатурные сокращения](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#keybindings))

---

Есть проблема, которая касается конкретно `gets` - изначально это метод [Kernel#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), который будет работать по-разному, в зависимости от того, переданы аргументы (ARGV) скрипту или нет. Чтобы читать из стрима терминала, рекоммендуется указывать это явно:

```
name = STDIN.gets.chomp
# или
name = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Источники:

- [Using gets() gives “No such file or directory” error when I pass arguments to my script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453569/using-gets-gives-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-i-pass-arguments-to-my)
- [Ruby: What's the difference between STDIN.gets() and gets.chomp()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041492/ruby-whats-the-difference-between-stdin-gets-and-gets-chomp)

Comment: Не удается установить Install Package. Возникает ошибка
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера>

Comment: Удалось установить SublimeREPL, но он не запускается. То есть,  скачал с git архив, распаковал в Папку ...Sublime Text Build 3083 x64\Data\Packages. Командами Ctrl + Shift + P ⇒ SublimeREPL: Ruby - видит его в списке, но ничего не происходит, когда запускаю и когда билдю. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @ToshiDono, а видно ли какие-то ошибки в консоли, когда запускается билд? `Ctrl + \`` - чтобы открыть консоль.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov, всё же разработка SublimeREPL прекратилась ещё на момент Вашего ответа, а баги остались. Полагаю его использование — не оптимальное решение. Об альтернативах расписал [**здесь**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544776/199934). Спасибо.