# Консоль Sublime Text 3

Tags: node.js, cmd, sublime-text

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить консоль в sublimetext3, чтобы не открывать стандартную консоль (cmd) в Windows?

Comment: А у вас есть другие? :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

В обзоре могут содержаться субъективные суждения, основанные на опыте работы с плагинами для Sublime Text.

---

### Протестировано на

- Windows 32-bit 10.0.14393,
- [**Отключён контроль учётных записей**](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-and-disable-uac-in-windows-10/),
- Sublime Text Build 3126.

Вообще в Sublime Text по моему вероятностному суждению примерно треть плагинов совсем не работают после установки. Но расписанные в обзоре лично у меня функционируют, что доказывается скринкастами.

По причине того, что использую Windows, не рассмотрены такие решения, как [**Tint**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Tint) и [**fish-shell**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/fish-shell). Если не упомянул что-то ещё, можете добавить.

---

### Терминология

В данном обзоре встроенная консоль Windows называется «консолью» или «внешней консолью» в зависимости от контекста. Согласно автору программы ConEmu называть её `cmd.exe` [**не совсем корректно**](http://www.conemu.ru/ru/Delusions.html#delusion-2):

> В Windows есть встроенный терминал (или “консольное окно”) которое часто ошибочно называют “cmd.exe”. Нажмите Win+R и запустите, например, “powershell.exe”. Среди запущенных процессов не будет “cmd.exe”. В разных версиях Windows консольное окно создают разные процессы, в актуальных – это “conhost.exe”.
>
> ```
>   Не ‘cmd.exe’, а просто ‘консоль’!
> ```

---

---

## 0. Не работающее решение

---

### 1. SublimePTY

[**Страница плагина**](https://github.com/wuub/SublimePTY). Разработка давно прекращена.

---

---

## 1. Для запуска отдельных команд

Для Sublime Text пишут плагины, облегчающие запуск только отдельных команд только для определённых инструментов программирования. Например, команды Git проще запускать с помощью плагинов [**Git**](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git), [**SideBar Git**](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarGit) и [**Easygit**](https://github.com/silentninja/easygit) (Не загружайте Easygit через Package Control, он [**не будет работать**](https://github.com/Ivanca/easygit/issues/3)! Установите плагин [**вручную**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=16) по [**ссылке**](https://github.com/silentninja/easygit)). Так как в вопросе указана метка `Node.js`, приведу в пример плагин `npm`.

---

### 1. npm

[**Плагин**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/npm), благодаря которому можно запускать [**многие команды**](https://github.com/PixnBits/sublime-text-npm#commands-implemented) npm — пакетного менеджера Node.js.

#### 1. Демонстрация

[image: npm]

#### 2. Недостатки

- [**Баги**](https://github.com/PixnBits/sublime-text-npm/issues/42). Не запускается ряд команд.

---

---

## 2. Эмуляция терминала прямо в Sublime Text

### Общая оценка

Все решения хорошие, пользуюсь ими, но полностью внешние терминалы они не заменяют.

---

### 1. Glue

#### 1. Оценка

Использую иногда.

#### 2. Демонстрация

[image: Glue]

#### 3. Установка и настройка

Скачиваем [**плагин**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Glue) через Package Control →

- В открытом файле проекта <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Glue - Launch`.
- Или же кликаете правой кнопкой мыши по папке в сайдбаре, в выпадающем меню выбираете `Open Glue Terminal`.

Откроется quick panel, куда следует вводить команды:

[image: Glue Quick Panel]

Появится файл `terminal.glue`. [**Без него никак**](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/glue/issues/52), если мешает, можете добавить расширение glue в `.gitignore`, `.hgignore` или другой файл, который используется для игнорирования директорий/файлов в Вашей системе контроля версий.

Чтобы в выводе была хоть какая-то подсветка, скачиваем плагин [**PowerShell**](https://github.com/SublimeText/PowerShell) → [**настраиваем**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513322/199934) для расширения `glue` синтаксис PowerShell.

#### 4. Достоинства

- Не нужно выходить из Sublime Text, чтобы запускать команды,
- Достаточно многофункциональный плагин,
- Удобнее осуществлять навигацию по output, если тот большой, во вкладке, нежели в консоли.

#### 5. Недостатки

- Разработка прекращена, шанс, что [**ответят на Ваш багрепорт**](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/glue/issues), минимален,
- А багов, которые не воспроизводятся в других терминалах, достаточно. Так, не рекомендовал бы пушить изменения Git через Glue.
- [**Лимиты**](http://gluedocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html). [**Cash**](https://github.com/dthree/cash) в Glue не запустишь.

#### 6. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Обзор Glue**](http://sweetme.at/2014/04/07/glue-a-terminal-for-sublime-text/),
- [**Собственные команды Glue**](http://gluedocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html),
- [**Инструкция по созданию и использованию алиасов в Glue**](http://gluedocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extend-glue.html).

---

### 2. SublimeREPL

Позволяет запускать REPL консоль для многих языков программирования во вкладке Sublime Text. В примере этого ответа написано, как настроить SublimeREPL для PowerShell.

#### 1. Оценка

Пользуюсь часто, но иногда вынужден прибегать к другим терминалам.

#### 2. Демонстрация

[image: SublimeREPL]

#### 3. Установка и настройка

Помимо самого SublimeREPL устанавливаем также плагины [**Suricate**](https://github.com/nsubiron/SublimeSuricate) и [**PowerShell**](https://github.com/SublimeText/PowerShell) для настройки команды SublimeREPL и подсветки синтаксиса соответственно.
[**Инструкция по настройке команд в Suricate**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934).

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `SublimeREPL: PowerShell` → если у Вас русская версия операционной системы, может вылезти всплывающее окно с примерно следующей ошибкой:

```
error: UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'C:\\Users\\\x8a\xae\xe2', 9, 10, 'invalid start byte')
```

[image: SublimeREPL encoding error]

В таком случае перейдите в файл `Default.suricate-profile` (как — см. [**инструкцию**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934), всё, что в ней есть, я буду опускать в данном ответе) → и вставьте следующий json-массив. Не путайтесь в [**JSON-синтаксисе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/238934/199934), следите за правильной расстановкой кавычек, скобок и запятых.

```json
// SublimeREPL PowerShell
"sublime_repl_powershell": {
    "caption": "SublimeREPL: PowerShell",
    "keys": ["super+alt+p"],
    "call": "sublime.repl_open",
    "args": {
        "type": "powershell",
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "cmd": ["powershell", "-"],
        "cwd": "$file_path",
        "external_id": "powershell",
        "syntax": "Packages/PowerShell/Support/PowerShellSyntax.tmLanguage"
    }
},
```

#### 4. Параметры аргументов

- `type` — тип. Означает, что во вкладке запустится консоль PowerShell, а не какая-либо другая вроде Python или Node.
- `encoding` — кодировка.
- `cmd` — запускаем PowerShell в консоли Windows.
- `cwd` — указываем [**системную переменную**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#build-system-variables). `$file_path` означает, что SublimeREPL PowerShell запустится в папке файла, находясь в котором мы запустили SublimeREPL PowerShell.
- `external_id` —

  - Во-первых, данным параметром определяется, как будет называться вкладка с PowerShell. Если оставить параметру пустое значение, `"external_id": ""`, то во вкладке будет указан полный путь к файлу `powershell.exe`:
    [image: Полный путь к powershell.exe]
    Мы назвали вкладку `powershell`, но можно по-любому. Если подставите значение `sashatriumph`, ничего не должно поломаться:
    [image: Именованный путь]
  - Во-вторых, значение параметра `external_id` является именем файла, где хранится история команд, когда-либо вводимых Вами в SublimeREPL PowerShell. Файл c расширением `.db` располагается по пути `Packages/User/.SublimeREPLHistory`.
- `syntax` — относительный путь к файлу синтаксиса для подсветки вкладки SublimeREPL PowerShell, начиная с Packages.

#### 5. Достоинства

- Не нужно выходить из Sublime Text, чтобы запускать команды,
- Удобнее осуществлять навигацию по output, если тот большой, во вкладке, нежели в консоли.
- Особенно нравится, что [**запоминаются все команды**](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), которые когда-либо вводили.

#### 6. Недостатки

- [**Кодировки**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40541447/5951529). Если приходится работать не только с английскими символами, ещё замучаетесь бороться с багами.
- Разработка прекращена, шанс, что [**ответят на Ваш багрепорт**](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/glue/issues), минимален,
- Не всё, что работает в PowerShell, работает в SublimeREPL PowerShell. Например, [**Cash**](https://github.com/dthree/cash) в Glue не запустишь. SublimeREPL PowerShell не получится заменить терминал полноценно.

#### 7. Дополнительная ссылка

- [**Документация SublimeREPL**](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

---

### 3. Terminality

В примере показан вывод для Python, но можно использовать как консоль и для других языков программирования, включая отсутствующие по умолчанию в плагине.

#### 1. Оценка

Использую для обучения Python и PHP.

#### 2. Демонстрация

[image: Terminality]

#### 3. Установка и настройка

Загружаем [**плагин**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality) через Package Control → открываем файл `hangman.py`, вывод из которого собираемся осуществить, → <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Terminality: Browse Commands...` → `Run hangman.py — <sub><sup>Run hangman.py as Python 2.7 document</sup></sub>` → видим результат в новой вкладке, включая время, потраченное на компиляцию, в сантисекундах. [**Обратите внимание**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality/issues/18#issuecomment-259389546), что пунктом меню `Run hangman.py as Python3` запускается команда `python3`, при выборе `Run hangman.py` — команда `python`. Даже когда у Вас установлен Python 3, а не Python 2, если исполняемый файл Python называется `python.exe`, а не `python3.exe`, выбирайте `Run hangman.py — <sub><sup>Run hangman.py as Python 2.7 document</sup></sub>`.

#### 4. Достоинства

- Не нужно выходить из Sublime Text, чтобы запускать команды,
- Удобнее осуществлять навигацию по output, если тот большой, во вкладке, нежели в консоли.
- Активно поддерживается разработчиками.

#### 5. Недостатки

- Некоторые баги, которые не воспроизводятся во внешних терминалах. «[**Although Terminality can run many commands, it is not gurranteed that it can be used for all commands**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality#what-is-terminality)».

#### 6. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Репозиторий плагина, где описываются его возможности**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality),
- [**Инструкция по настройке Terminality для не настроенных в плагине нативно языков программирования на примере PHP**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571848/199934).

---

---

## 3. Запуск из Sublime Text внешних терминалов

Достоинства и недостатки относятся уже к вызываемым в Sublime Text терминалам, а не самому Sublime Text.

---

### 1. Консоль/GNOME Terminal

#### 1. Установка и настройка

Устанавливаем плагин [**Suricate**](https://github.com/nsubiron/SublimeSuricate). <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Suricate: Open Terminal Here...` → откроется новое окно с консолью для Windows и GNOME Terminal для Linux соответственно в директории с тем файлом, который был у Вас открыт, когда запускали терминал.

#### 2. Параметры и их значения

Как выглядит конфигурационный файл Suricate:

```json
// Open terminal.
"open_terminal_here":
{
  "call":         "Suricate.lib.process.spawn",
  "caption":      "Open Terminal Here...",
  "flags":        "Windows|Linux",
  "args.windows": {"cmd": ["start", "cmd.exe"], "working_dir": "${file_path}"},
  "args.linux":   {"cmd": ["gnome-terminal"], "working_dir": "${file_path}"},
},
```

(В оригинальном массиве также есть параметры/значения `"group": "launch"`, `|IsFile`, `"context_menu": true`, каковые я опустил в силу того, что считаю их излишними.)

- `flags` — параметр, при помощи которого можно задать различные аргументы для операционных систем или систем управления версиями.
- `args.windows` и `args.linux` — параметры запуска терминалов Windows и Linux.

#### Дополнительная ссылка

- [**См. данный ответ и ссылки в его конце**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934)

---

### 2. Запуск любого предпочтительного терминала

Для примера возьмём, как запустить Git Bash из Sublime Text.

#### 1. Установка и настройка

Устанавливаем плагин [**Suricate**](https://github.com/nsubiron/SublimeSuricate) → в файл `Default.suricate-profile` добавляем следующий код:

```json
//  Запустить Git Bash
"git-bash": {
    "call": "Suricate.lib.process.spawn",
    "args.windows": {
        "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"],
        "working_dir": "${file_path}"
    },
    "caption": "Git Bash",
    "keys": ["<c>+super+keypad3"],
},
```

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Suricate: Git Bash` → должен открыться Git Bash в директории с тем файлом, который был у Вас открыт, когда запускали Git Bash из Sublime Text.

#### 2. Дополнительная ссылка

- [**См. данный ответ и ссылки в его конце**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934)

---

### 3. Плагин Terminal

#### 1. Описание

Кроссплатформенный плагин, позволяющий открывать из Sublime Text любой терминал, который лично Вы считаете наиболее предпочтительным. В Windows по умолчанию запускается PowerShell. После установки [**плагина**](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal) доступны 3 варианта запуска:

- Из command palette,
- Из контекстного меню сайдбара,
- Шорткатом. Многим пользователям [**не нравится**](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/issues/17), что задействуется сочетание, по умолчанию используемое для переоткрытия последней закрытой вкладки, можете [**перезаписать**](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/issues/17#issuecomment-205554949) шорткат в файле пользовательского кеймапа.

Вызываются две команды:

- `open_terminal` — открывает терминал в папке, где лежит файл, вкладка с которым была открыта, когда запускали терминал.
- `open_terminal_project_folder` — возможно, работает некорректно. Актуальное поведение:

  - Если Вы запустили команду, из файла, который находится в верхней папке Вашего сайдбара или её подпапках, терминал запустится в этой верхней папке. Например, мой сайдбар:
    [image: Сайдбар]
    Когда я запускаю `open_terminal_project_folder`, например, из файла `E:\Киролайна\SashaFolder\SashaFile.txt`, терминал откроется в `E:\Киролайна`.
  - Но когда Вы запускаете команду из файла, не имеющего отношения к верхней папке Вашего сайдбара — в моём случае `E:\Киролайна`, — поведение команды `open_terminal_project_folder` аналогично поведению `open_terminal`.

#### 2. Настройка

Вы можете указывать параметры запуска Вашего терминала. Положим, хотите всегда запускать консольный эмулятор [**cmder**](http://cmder.net/) только из директории E:\SashaSublime.

Для упрощения работы с настройками Sublime Text скачиваем плагин [**Preferences Editor**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Preferences%20Editor). <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Edit Preferences: Edit Settings...` → `Terminal` → `terminal` → в открывшуюся quick panel вставляете путь к исполняемому файлу cmder.exe вместе с именем файла, например, `E:\Chocolatey\tools\cmder\Cmder.exe` → <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Далее <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Edit Preferences: Edit Settings...` → `Terminal` → `parameters` → между квадратными скобками вставляем `"/START", "E:\\SashaSublime"` → <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Обратите внимание, что если значения заключены в [квадратные скобки], необходимо экранировать слэши: `E:\Chocolatey\tools\cmder\Cmder.exe`, но `E:\\SashaSublime`.

Теперь после запуска любой из команд — `open_terminal` либо `open_terminal_project_folder` должен открыться `Cmder.exe` в папке `E:\SashaSublime`.

Также предусмотрена возможность одним шорткатом запускать один терминал со своими параметрами, вторым хоткеем запускать другой терминал с другими параметрами и т. д. Читаем [**здесь**](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal#custom-parameters).

#### 3. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Краткое описание плагина Terminal в книге «Sublime Text Power User»**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=53),
- [**Репозиторий плагина на GitHub**](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal)

---

### 4. ConEmu

Для [**лучшей, по мнению пользователей англоязычного Stack Overflow, консоли для Windows**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/5951529) есть [**свой плагин**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ConEmuOpen). См. также [**плагин для Cmder**](https://github.com/Starli0n/SublimeCmder) — немного изменённого ConEmu.

#### 1. Описание

По умолчанию [**осуществляется**](https://github.com/kiliwalk/Sublime_ConEmuOpen/pull/5/commits/a1773936a7dac91092526606a375f13f5ba952bd?diff=unified) запуск PowerShell в оболочке ConEmu. Как и в плагине Terminal, ConEmu можно запустить из command palette, контекстного меню сайдбара или шорткатом.

- `open_conemu_here` — открывает ConEmu в папке, где лежит файл, вкладка с которым была открыта, когда запускали ConEmu.
- `open_conemu_project` — возможно, работает некорректно. Всегда открывает ConEmu в верхней папке сайдбара, в моём случае (см. п. 3.3) это `E:\Киролайна`.

#### 2. Недостатки

- Разработчик перешёл на [**MacOS**](https://github.com/kiliwalk/Sublime_ConEmuOpen/issues/4#issuecomment-250635923), плагин больше не поддерживается.
- Баги. я [**пофиксил**](https://github.com/kiliwalk/Sublime_ConEmuOpen/pull/5), что нашёл, но далеко не факт, что их больше не осталось.

#### 3. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Альтернативный терминал для Windows — статья на Хабрахабре**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164687/),
- [**Официальный сайт ConEmu**](http://www.conemu.ru/),
- [**Документация ConEmu**](http://www.conemu.ru/ru/TableOfContents.html).

---

---

## 4. Обратное решение — вывод во внешнюю консоль

---

### 1. Console Exec

#### 1. Оценка

Пользуюсь вместо дефолтных Build System.

#### 2. Описание

[**Плагин**](https://github.com/joeyespo/sublimetext-console-exec) выводит результаты Build System во внешнюю консоль, а не встроенную Sublime Text. Это может понадобиться [**по ряду причин**](https://github.com/joeyespo/sublimetext-console-exec#why).

- Если после вывода требуется вводить что-то ещё в консоль , — дефолтным механизмом Build System без дополнительных надстроек [**не обойтись**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478513/199934). Установив же Console Exec и добавив в файл Build System всего одну дополнительную строку, Вы можете и дальше вводить команды.
- Если пользуетесь плагином [**Build Next**](https://github.com/albertosantini/sublimetext-buildnext), когда в выводе нет ошибок, встроенная панель Build System автоматически закрывается. Использование внешней панели средствами Console Exec избавляет от данной проблемы.
- Встроенная панель не поддерживает некоторые средства программирования как [**Pyglet**](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home).
- В панели Build System неудобна навигация. Увеличишь панель Build System — не будет видно содержимого вкладок, уменьшишь — вывода в панель.
- Выводя результаты во внешнюю консоль, при закрытии Sublime Text внешняя консоль остаётся открытой — дополнительное удобство.

#### 3. Демонстрация

[image: ConsoleExec]

#### 4. Настройка

После установки плагина достаточно добавить в файл Build System одну дополнительную строку:

```
"target": "console_exec"
```

Пример для Python. `Tools` → `Builds System` → `New Build System...` → вставляем следующий код и сохраняем файл, например, под именем `SashaPythonExec.sublime-build`:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "target": "console_exec"
}
```

Как создавать и настроить автоматический выбор Build System, подробно рассмотрено по дополнительным ссылкам.

Во вкладке со скриптом на Python <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Build With: SashaPythonExec` → смотрим результат.

#### 5. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Документация по использованию Build System в Sublime Text**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html),
- [**Описание Build System в книге «Sublime Text Power User»**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=127),
- [**Некоторые готовые Build System для компьютерных языков и инструментов программирования**](https://addyosmani.com/blog/custom-sublime-text-build-systems-for-popular-tools-and-languages/),
- [**Настройка автоматического выбора Build System**](https://toster.ru/q/326804#answer_850517).

---

### 2. Send to Shell

В Sublime Text существуют плагины, отправляющие во внешний терминал выделенный или скопированный текст, как [**SendText**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SendText) и [**SendREPL**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SendREPL). Тот же принцип действия у плагина [**Send to Shell**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Send%20to%20Shell), отправляющего скопированный текст в [**IPython**](https://ipython.org/) — интерактивную оболочку для Python, составляющую [**Jupyter**](https://jupyter.org/).

#### 1. Демонстрация

[image: IPython]

#### 2. Установка

Как настроить плагин для отправки скопированного текста на ConEmu в режиме PowerShell.

- Скачиваем и устанавливаем [**последнюю версию Python**](https://www.python.org/downloads/), если Python ещё не установлен в системе.
- Устанавливаем Jupyter, проще всего, [**запустив в терминале команду**](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id4) `pip install jupyter`.
- Устанавливаем через Package Control [**PyWin32**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pywin32) — набор расширений Python для доступа ко многим функциям Windows API.
- Устанавливаем через Package Control плагин [**Preferences Editor**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Preferences%20Editor) для упрощения работы с файлами настроек Sublime Text.
- Устанавливаем через Package Control плагин Send to Shell.

#### 3. Настройка

[**Задаём системную переменную PATH**](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml), указав в качестве значения путь к файлу `ConEmu.exe`, для меня это `C:\Program Files\ConEmu`.

Запускаем ConEmu → <kbd>Super+Alt+P</kbd> → `Startup` → задаём параметру `Specifed named task` значение `{Shells::PowerShell}`:

[image: Установка PowerShell в ConEmu]

В Sublime Text 3 <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Edit Preferences: Edit <kbd>Settings...` → `SendToShell` → `powershell_startup` → в открывшееся поле вместо `powershell` вписываем `conemu`. Ctrl+Shift+P → `Edit Preferences: Edit Settings...` → `SendToShell` → `window_title` → в открывшееся поле вместо `Windows PowerShell` вписываем заголовок вкладки ConEmu: у меня это `powershell (Admin)`.

Опционально предлагаю установить плагин [**CopyOnSelect**](https://github.com/chrifpa/CopyOnSelect), — пусть по первому времени он вызвать неудобства, — копирующий в буфер обмена выделенный текст. Задержка между выделением текста и его копированием в данном плагине составляет секунду, и автор [**не рекомендует**](https://github.com/chrifpa/CopyOnSelect/blob/master/CopyOnSelect.sublime-settings) её сильно уменьшать из-за возможных проблем с работой Clipboard-менеджеров.

Настройка окончена. Выделяем кусок скрипта на Python для отправки в ConEmu → копируем его (а с плагином CopyOnSelect достаточно только выделить) → запускаем команду `sendtoshell {"how": "paste_selection"},` — по умолчанию сочетанием клавиш <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>, — в ConEmu пишем команду `ipython`, а затем `%paste`. Можно было, конечно, написать плагин так, [**чтобы пользователь совершал поменьше действий**](https://github.com/Twizzledrizzle/Send-to-Shell/issues/1).

#### 4. Недостатки

- [**Баги в установке связи плагина с терминалом**](https://github.com/Twizzledrizzle/Send-to-Shell/issues/1).

#### 5. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Оболочка IPython как инструмент системного администратора (python freebsd shell)**](https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/ipython_sysadmin.txt.html),
- [**IPython: замена стандартного Python shell**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/49685/).

---

---

## 5. Поиск плагинов

Если описанные в обзоре плагины не удовлетворяют Вашим задачам, помимо обычного поиска в Google порекомендовал бы осуществить поиск примерно по следующим ключевым словам и меткам на сайте [**Package Control**](https://packagecontrol.io/):

- [**terminal**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/terminal),
- [**build system**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/build%20system),
- [**console**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/console),
- [**repl**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/repl),
- [**shell**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/shell).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подробный материал. А как предотвратить автоматическое закрытие консоли win 10 в случае с использованием Console Exec? Сейчас открывается консоль, выполняется программа, потом "нажмите любую клавишу..." и никакой возможности ввести интерактивном режиме команды. :(