# Как настроить SublimeREPL для Python, чтобы он понимал русские буквы?

Tags: python, sublime-text

В системном интерпретаторе Linux отображение кириллических символов для Python корректное, а через Sublime Text 3 не могу добиться нормального отображения. В чём проблема?

В настройках SublimeREPL стоит строчка

```
`"default_extend_env": {"PYTHONPATH": "/usr/bin/python3"},`
```

Пробовал и `/usr/bin/python` и долго игрался с другими настройками, эффекта ноль. На Windows всё работало нормально, но на Linux проблемы.

Если в Sublime Text 3 запустить следующий код,

```
print(1, "Привет", 2)
```

То при выполнении выскочит вполне понятная ошибка:

```
File "untitled.py", line 1 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character 
'\xd0' in file untitled.py on line 1, but no encoding declared;
see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Если выполнить такой код,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print(1, "Привет", 2)
```

То отрабатывает без ошибок, но на выходе это:

```
(1, '\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82', 2)

***Repl Closed***
```

Замена в коде `#!/usr/bin/python` на `#!/usr/bin/python3` Также ничего не изменило

Comment: Дайте попробую угадать: в системе Python 3, а в sublime Python 2?

Comment: @andreymal, в настройках sublimeREPL стоит строчка
"default_extend_env": {"PYTHONPATH": "/usr/bin/python3"},
все равно не помогает. на винде все работало нормально а на линуксе проблемы

Comment: Начните с **минимального** примера кода, который демонстрирует проблему, например: `print("hello \U0001F602 мир!")` (это весь код). [mcve] Приведите результаты в терминале и из вашего редактора. По возможности в виде текста, а не картинки (если не знаете как в вашем окружении текст скопировать—спросите). Кстати, PYTHONPATH это переменная окружения, используемая для `sys.path`—она должна быть пуста обычно и пути к исполняемому файлу python3 там делать нечего, даже если она не пустая.

Comment: @Михаил PYTHONPATH - путь к каталогу с модулями питона, а не к самому питону, а питон всё ещё может оказаться вторым

Comment: В дополнение к комментарию jfs рекомендую ещё сделать `print(1, "Привет", 2)` и все результаты аналогично сюда (через редактирование вопроса)

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: как вам @andreymal сказал, у вас sublime использует Python 2, а код у вас написан вероятно для Python 3. Если не знаете как запустить Питон-скрипт в sublimе, используя Python 3, то задайте отдельный вопрос (это может быть полезно, не только для вас, не только в контексте вывода текста).

Comment: @Михаил, (у меня на Windows 10 проблема не воспроизводится). Вместо попыток отладки SublimeREPL порекомендовал бы использовать [**альтернативы SublimeREPL и дефолтной Build System — Terminality или Console Exec**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544776/199934). Аргументы расписал в ответе по ссылке. Разработка SublimeREPL давно прекращена, помощь от самих разработчиков никак не получишь. Вместе с тем баги с кодировками никуда не делись, тоже [**не могу их побороть**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40541447/5951529). Спасибо.

Comment: @jfs, `у вас sublime использует Python 2,` — автор вопроса упомянул, что у него Sublime Text 3. Если он не пользуется устаревшими версиями, то в Sublime Text, начиная с Build 3124, [**используется Python 3.3**](https://www.sublimetext.com/3). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных посмотрите на вывод в вопросе: нет ни тени сомнения что это Питон 2 вывод. Подумайте как выглядит `print(1,2)` в Питоне 2 и 3.