# Кодировка в sublime text 3 кириллицы

Tags: python, utf-8, sublime-text, unicode, sublime-text-3

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с этой гадкой проблемой кодировки в саблайме, может кому удалось решить ее? Буду очень благодарен !

[image: Проблема!]

Comment: В результате каких действий у вас окно нижнее с сообщениями выводится?

Comment: При компиляции, т.е. Ctrl+B, и вот такая бубуйня, с английскими словами все хорошо. Все PATH  прописаны. Не знаю что делать, подскажите если знаете.

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: @Alexey: не рекомендовал бы использовать нативную Build System. Обратите внимание на [**более совершенные средства**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544776/199934). Спасибо.