# Как сделать подобное?

Tags: sublime-text

Как сделать некий 'Split Screen' в SublimeText3, чтобы внизу была консоль (командная строка)?
возможно какие-то плагины

Как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно похожий вопрос: [ссылочка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529154/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-sublime-text-3)

Comment: h4cktivist, Это давно уже все не актуально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственная адекватная консолька для саблайма - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus

[image: Terminus]

В ней нужно слегка разобраться, но способна заменить даже SublimeREPL